# Merge list of dicts with common datestamp

Tags: python

My list contains about 100+ dicts with a `month` and various status totals:

```
 [{'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='UTC')), 'total': 1, 'Win': 0, 'Loss': 1, 'Open': 0, 'Dormant': 0, 'Pending': 0, 'Cancelled': 0}
{'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='UTC')), 'total': 1, 'Win': 0, 'Loss': 0, 'Open': 1, 'Dormant': 0, 'Pending': 0, 'Cancelled': 0}
{'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='UTC')), 'total': 1, 'Win': 0, 'Loss': 1, 'Open': 0, 'Dormant': 0, 'Pending': 0, 'Cancelled': 0}
{'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='UTC')), 'total': 1, 'Win': 0, 'Loss': 1, 'Open': 0, 'Dormant': 0, 'Pending': 0, 'Cancelled': 0}
{'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='UTC')), 'total': 1, 'Win': 0, 'Loss': 0, 'Open': 1, 'Dormant': 0, 'Pending': 0, 'Cancelled': 0}
{'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='UTC')), 'total': 1, 'Win': 0, 'Loss': 0, 'Open': 1, 'Dormant': 0, 'Pending': 0, 'Cancelled': 0}
{'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='UTC')), 'total': 1, 'Win': 0, 'Loss': 0, 'Open': 1, 'Dormant': 0, 'Pending': 0, 'Cancelled': 0}]
```

The goal would be to condense all dicts so there is only one dict per common timestamp.

The desired output for the above example would be:

```
[{'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='UTC')), 'total': 1, 'Win': 0, 'Loss': 1, 'Open': 0, 'Dormant': 0, 'Pending': 0, 'Cancelled': 0}
    {'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='UTC')), 'total': 4, 'Win': 0, 'Loss': 2, 'Open': 2, 'Dormant': 0, 'Pending': 0, 'Cancelled': 0}
    {'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='UTC')), 'total': 1, 'Win': 0, 'Loss': 0, 'Open': 1, 'Dormant': 0, 'Pending': 0, 'Cancelled': 0}
    {'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='UTC')), 'total': 1, 'Win': 0, 'Loss': 0, 'Open': 1, 'Dormant': 0, 'Pending': 0, 'Cancelled': 0}]
```

What is the most efficient way to condense these down? I tried looping through each object to look at the previous object, but this became to time taxing of a solution.

Comment: I would suggest sorting and then using `itertools.groupby`, but then I would also recommend showing us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an intermediate dictionary where the datestamp is the key, and the value is your statistics.  When you're done, it will be easy to convert that back to your list.

```
import datetime

data = [{'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 1, 0, 0), 'total': 1, 'Win': 0, 'Loss': 1, 'Open': 0, 'Dormant': 0, 'Pending': 0, 'Cancelled': 0},
{'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 1, 0, 0), 'total': 1, 'Win': 0, 'Loss': 0, 'Open': 1, 'Dormant': 0, 'Pending': 0, 'Cancelled': 0},
{'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 1, 0, 0), 'total': 1, 'Win': 0, 'Loss': 1, 'Open': 0, 'Dormant': 0, 'Pending': 0, 'Cancelled': 0},
{'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 1, 0, 0), 'total': 1, 'Win': 0, 'Loss': 1, 'Open': 0, 'Dormant': 0, 'Pending': 0, 'Cancelled': 0},
{'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 1, 0, 0), 'total': 1, 'Win': 0, 'Loss': 0, 'Open': 1, 'Dormant': 0, 'Pending': 0, 'Cancelled': 0},
{'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 1, 0, 0), 'total': 1, 'Win': 0, 'Loss': 0, 'Open': 1, 'Dormant': 0, 'Pending': 0, 'Cancelled': 0},
{'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 1, 0, 0), 'total': 1, 'Win': 0, 'Loss': 0, 'Open': 1, 'Dormant': 0, 'Pending': 0, 'Cancelled': 0}]

dct = {}
for row in data:
    if row['month'] not in dct:
        dct[row['month']] = row
    else:
        for k,v in row.items():
            if k != 'month':
                dct[row['month']][k] += v

data = list(dct.values())
for row in data:
    print(row)
```

Output:

```
{'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 1, 0, 0), 'total': 1, 'Win': 0, 'Loss': 1, 'Open': 0, 'Dormant': 0, 'Pending': 0, 'Cancelled': 0}
{'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 1, 0, 0), 'total': 4, 'Win': 0, 'Loss': 2, 'Open': 2, 'Dormant': 0, 'Pending': 0, 'Cancelled': 0}
{'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 1, 0, 0), 'total': 1, 'Win': 0, 'Loss': 0, 'Open': 1, 'Dormant': 0, 'Pending': 0, 'Cancelled': 0}
{'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 1, 0, 0), 'total': 1, 'Win': 0, 'Loss': 0, 'Open': 1, 'Dormant': 0, 'Pending': 0, 'Cancelled': 0}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Tim- this is great that the output can easily be converted back. Appreciate your help!

Comment: It doesn't have to be converted.  It's stored in an array of dicts, exactly as you wanted.  I just happened to PRINT the lines individually, to get them spaced all pretty.

Answer (score 1):

My approach is pretty much the same as the one used by Tim Roberts, except that I'm using Counter type from collections module.

```
from collections import Counter

newdata = {}
for d in data:
    month = d.get('month')
    del d['month']
    if month in newdata:
        newdata[month].update(d)
    else:
        newdata[month] = Counter(d)

data = [{'month': k, **v} for (k, v) in newdata.items()]
```

Output of data:

```
[{'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='UTC')), 'total': 1, 'Win': 0, 'Loss': 1, 'Open': 0, 'Dormant': 0, 'Pending': 0, 'Cancelled': 0},
{'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='UTC')), 'total': 4, 'Win': 0, 'Loss': 2, 'Open': 2, 'Dormant': 0, 'Pending': 0, 'Cancelled': 0},
{'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='UTC')), 'total': 1, 'Win': 0, 'Loss': 0, 'Open': 1, 'Dormant': 0, 'Pending': 0, 'Cancelled': 0},
{'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='UTC')), 'total': 1, 'Win': 0, 'Loss': 0, 'Open': 1, 'Dormant': 0, 'Pending': 0, 'Cancelled': 0}]
```

Comment: Thanks so much- this was a very simple solution to implement!